# Улучшить наглядность теста для функции поиска по множеству параметров

Tags: тестирование, testng

Может, кто знает красивое решение для такой ситуации. Есть некий алгоритм, с кучей входных параметров, надо его протестировать. Но чем больше условий для теста описываешь, тем не красивее становится код и мало понятным. Например, ищем людей по условиям имя, возраст, город проживания, хобби.

Сначала добавляем данные в хранилище

```
h1 = {name: Alex, age: 22, city: Ekb, hobbies: [cars, girls]}
h2 = {name: Kate, age: 32, city: Msc, hobbies: [cars]}
rep.save(h1, h2) // etc
```

Потом проверяем что выборка дает именно нужный нам результат

```
humans = find(Alex, 22, Ekb)
assertCount(humbas, 1)
assertContains(humans, h1)
```

И чем больше становится записей о людей и проверок, тем сложнее понять тест. Есть ли способ повысить наглядность теста?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно Вас смущает. Может, приложите полный код теста для примера? Если тест сложно понять, скорее всего он не правильно спроектирован.